# in need of an arduino i2c lcd libary

Tags: arduino

I have a Uno R3 ATmega328  that I can't seem to match a i2c LCD library with (I have a 20x4 LCD). I see websites that offer it with broken links.  Can someone tell me where I can get the right library at?  also which IDE I should be using with this board for windows 7?
   Thanks all

Comment: Posts asking for off-site resources are considered off-topic. Opinion-based questions ("which IDE should I be using?") are also off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the wire library (included w/ arduino ide) and the library for the lcd is [here](https://github.com/fdebrabander/Arduino-LiquidCrystal-I2C-library)